# Render Font Awesome from Json?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I trying to dynamically make a nav bar.

I have a component called "NavItem"

```
    import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

    export default class NavItem extends Component {
      render() {
          const props = this.props;
          const item = props.item;
          console.log(item.icon);
        return (
           <li> 
               <Link to={item.path}> { ReactHtmlParser(item.icon) }  </Link>
           </li>
        );
      }

}
```

This gets called in another component and rendered through a "map"

My json looks like this

```
   [
        {
            path: '/',
            icon: '<i className="fas fa-home" />',
            toolTip: 'Home'
        },
]
```

My code does not seem to render anything. I just see white space where the icon should be.

When I look at it through the dev tools in chrome I just see:  `<i className="fas fa-home" />`

So it does not seem like it is rendering it.

I have different icons from different libraries that is why I am not just storing the "classNames" in the json and the whole tag.

Comment: are you using the JS or CSS way of loading in Font Awesome?

Comment: JS way: using @fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.13",

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I had the same issue and eventually solved it like this.

IconMapping.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    faPlusCircle,
    faChevronDown,
    faWrench
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

export default {
    'faPlusCircle': <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle} />,
    'faChevronDown': <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronDown} />,
    'faWrench': <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWrench} />
};
```

Then in the component that you want the icons in

```
import iconMap from '../../iconMapping';
```

and in your loop of JSON data

```
<a href={subitem.url} >
  {iconMap[subitem.icon]}
  {subitem.name}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including the font-awesome library. Check the `sources` tab in `dev-tools` and make sure font-awesome is being included.

If you are using the most recent version (Font Awesome 5), make sure you are importing the fonts correctly https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use

edit: If you are using HTML inside `JSON` try setting `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: item.icon} } />`

Comment: yes, it is being included. It works perfectly fine when it is not coming from a json file if I do <i className={item.icon} /> all is well. It is just when the entire element is in the json string.

Comment: Updated my answer, have you tried using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Comment: Yes, I tried using react-html-parser and dangerouslySetInnerHTML yet both just render the html but I don't think it does the step of rendering it into the svg/javascript.